# Remove specific character from a cell depending on the cell value

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Can someone help on this? I have column A with telephone number and Column B with country code. I want to remove the country code in column A if it is there to avoid duplication. Can someone help me?

```
Column A 1234567
Column B 1
Column C 1234567
```

Column C should have the formula to check if 1 is already in the beginning of the cell value A, if yes, it'll remove it, but if not, column B value will be added to it. Another scenario is below:
Column A 234567
Column B 1
Column C 1234567

Appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
=IF(TEXT(B1,"0") = LEFT(TEXT(A1,"0"), LEN(B1)),A1,CONCATENATE(B1,A1))
```

The logic is fairly straight-forward - take as many characters as the length of your country-code from the full number, and see if they equal the country code. If they do, ignore the country code, and just display the number; otherwise concatenate the two values.

Not sure why 'text' is needed, but fair enough I guess.

Comment: text is required because `LEFT()` returns text.  `TEXT(A1,"0")` inside the `LEFT()` should not be needed.  you can also do: `=IF(B1 = --LEFT(A1, LEN(B1)),A1,--(B1&A1))`

Comment: I figured out a way to do it. Will try this as well. Thanks anyways! Appreciate the answer :)

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah, I guessed it was something like that. This gave me gyp the other day in MySQL:

select if(0='a',1,0) as oops;

Comment: @ScottCraner I have a follow-up on this one. How about adding a separator between the country code (B1) then 3 digits after it usong the formula you shared with me, so the output will be 1|234|4567

Comment: @Edey new questions get new posts.

Comment: @Scott Craner can you check this? I posted new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64600639/appending-separators-in-the-formula/64600947#64600947