# Appending separators in the formula

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Can someone help on this? I have column A with telephone number and Column B with country code. I want to remove the country code in column A if it is there to avoid duplication. Can someone help me?

Column A 1234567 Column B 1 Column C 1234567

Column C should have the formula to check if 1 is already in the beginning of the cell value A, if yes, it'll remove it, but if not, column B value will be added to it. Another scenario is below: Column A 234567 Column B 1 Column C 1234567

Also, I would like to add separators in this formula after the country code, and after three digits of the country code based on column 1 with removed country code in it.

How to append it in this formula?

=IF(B1 = --LEFT(A1, LEN(B1)),A1,--(B1&A1))

Appreciate your answer!

Comment: Which three digits of the country code are you talking about in that last paragraph? It would be more useful if you posted an example of some real phone number formats and real country codes and the real result you are after instead of just 12345678.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand what you describe, you may be after something like this:

```
="+"&TEXT(B1,"0")&"-"&
IF(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"0"),LEN(TEXT(B1,"0")))=TEXT(B1,"0"),
   MID(TEXT(A1,"0"),LEN(TEXT(B1,"0"))+1,99),
   A1)
```

[image]

The statement about "after three digits of the country code based on column 1 " is unclear. This formula gives you tools to add characters before and after the country code, while it removes country code duplication.

**edit after comments** You don't really describe it, at least not clearly, but it looks like you want a vertical bar after the country code and again after the first three digits of the phone number. The formula to achieve that is

```
=TEXT(B1,"0")&"|"&
REPLACE(IF(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"0"),LEN(TEXT(B1,"0")))=TEXT(B1,"0"),
   MID(TEXT(A1,"0"),LEN(TEXT(B1,"0"))+1,99),
   A1),4,1,"|")
```

[image]

**another edit after stitching together what else you might want but don't clearly describe:** If column B can possibly contain either numbers like `1` or `63` but also text that starts with a country code, followed by a space and some other stuff, like `63 2`, then you can use this formula

```
=LEFT(TEXT(B2,"0"),FIND(" ",TEXT(B2,"0")&" ")-1)&"|"&
REPLACE(IF(LEFT(TEXT(A2,"0"),LEN(TEXT(B2,"0")))=TEXT(B2,"0"),
   MID(TEXT(A2,"0"),LEN(TEXT(B2,"0"))+1,99),
   A2),4,1,"|")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @teylyn, I would like to have column B (country code) added to column A (phone) if it is not there. I.E. B2=63 A2=23445898 C2=63|234|45898 and B2=63 2=6323445898 C2=63|234|45898

Comment: @Scott Craner can you check?

Comment: I added a formula to my answer

Comment: Or are you saying that column B can contain values like `64 2` ?? Please **edit your question** and put in some more data samples that cover your different scenarios. Don't make it so hard for us to help you. Again, don't put these details into comments. **edit your question**

Comment: Apologies, I haven't used this platform much. But now I will, thabks for the reminder and for the help as well :) @teylyn